# Procedure of finding ideals that contain another ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Find the maximal ideals of $\Bbb R[x]/\langle x^2 \rangle$.

I know that the ideals of $\Bbb R[x]/\langle x^2 \rangle$ are in a bijective correspondence with the ideals of $\Bbb R[x]$ that contain $\langle x^2 \rangle$ and since $\Bbb R[x]$ is a field every ideal is principal.

So to determine the maximal ideals of $\Bbb R[x]/\langle x^2 \rangle$ I need to find ideals  of $\Bbb R[x]$ containing $\langle x^2 \rangle$.

What is the procedure of starting to find ideals containing some other ideal? If $\langle x^2 \rangle = \{a(x)x^2\mid a \in \Bbb R[x] \}$ then every element in $\langle x^2 \rangle$ is at least of degree $2$ so I think that $\langle x^2 \rangle \subset \langle x\rangle$ for example as I can generate every second degree polynomial with $g(x)x$, when $g$ is of degree $1$? It seems that for every constant polynomial $c$ we also have that $\langle x^2 \rangle \subset \langle c\rangle$ as I can generate every second degree and larger polynomials just by multiplying them with $c$?

Comment: Why close this one? It's clear that the dupe doesn't answer my question.

Comment: One link from the duplicate is [this one](http://brianbi.ca/artin/11.8). It should answer your question, i.e., Exercise 11.8.2. part (b) with solution. For ideals in a PID, to contain is to divide.

Comment: @Jaipur This forum has a strange rule, some users can close questions. I have seen lots of questions being closed when the "duplicate" wasn't even relevant. Clearly they should have changed the rules a long time ago.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Saw that one also. It doesn't answer the question which was "how to start to find ideals containing some other ideal?". I don't really care about the answer for this problem what I care about is how to do this in a general sense. The problem is just for demonstration.

Comment: I am sorry, if your question is only to answer $(x^2)\subset (c)$ then the answer is  is just $c$ dividing $x^2$ in $\Bbb R[x]$. This is another duplicate then.

Comment: @Jaipur Every ideal in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is generated by a unique monic polynomial. So you just have to find the monic polynomials which divide $x^2$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Well, in this specific question it isn't that important. I already pretty much answered the question in the comments.

Comment: @Mark thanks for the answer. I think that the only polynomial that divides $x^2$ is $x$, but the answer for this problem was $(x + (x^2))$ and not $(x)$?

Comment: @Jaipur The monic polynomials which divide $x^2$ are $1, x, x^2$, so there are $3$ ideals in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ which contain $(x^2)$. If you are interested in maximal ideals, you need only the irreducible monic polynomials which divide $x^2$. In our case this is indeed only $x$. So $(x)$ is the only maximal ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ which contains $(x^2)$, and so $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$ has just one maximal ideal, which is $(x+(x^2))$.